# When I run my JAR File I keep running into : "no main manifest attribute", How do I fix this?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, manifest, executable-jar

I am currently trying to host my spring project on AWS and am trying to run my JAR file once in the EC2 instance, but I run into this error:

```html
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-6-194 ~]$ java -jar debateeventplatform-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
no main manifest attribute, in debateeventplatform-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I saw that my JAR didn't have a manifest file so I added it through a maven plug-in showing:

```html
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Shreyes
JavaFX-Version: 17
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
Main-Class: me.shreyeschekuru.dsa.Application
```

But the error is still there. How do I fix this?

**Edit**
I managed to fix the no manifest error by adding in the necessary Maven-plugins into my pom file but now I run into an unable to find/load main class error:

```html
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-6-194 ~]$ java -jar debateeventplatform-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class me.shreyeschekuru.dsa.Application
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/flow/component/page/AppShellConfigurator
```

It seems like my main class directory is correct, how do I fix this?

My Manifest file:

```html
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Shreyes
JavaFX-Version: 17
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
Main-Class: me.shreyeschekuru.dsa.Application
```

My Main Class:

```html
package me.shreyeschekuru.dsa;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.NpmPackage;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.AppShellConfigurator;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.lumo.Lumo;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import me.shreyeschekuru.dsa.data.service.SamplePersonRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

/**
 * The entry point of the Spring Boot application.
 *
 * Use the @PWA annotation make the application installable on phones, tablets
 * and some desktop browsers.
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@NpmPackage(value = "@fontsource/barlow", version = "4.5.0")
@Theme(value = "debateeventplatform", variant = Lumo.DARK)
@Push
public class Application implements AppShellConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
        Class c = java.lang.Character.Subset.class;
        String innerClassName = c.getName();
        System.out.println("The fully qualified name of the inner class is: " + innerClassName);
        */

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer(DataSource dataSource,
            SqlInitializationProperties properties, SamplePersonRepository repository) {
        // This bean ensures the database is only initialized when empty
        return new SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer(dataSource, properties) {
            @Override
            public boolean initializeDatabase() {
                if (repository.count() == 0L) {
                    return super.initializeDatabase();
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include (at least) your `pom.xml`; preferably also add enough source code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Go ahead and paste the actual code and error (as text) in.  The pictures just get in the way.

Comment: That Manifest looks good, and the Main-Class matches a class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.  Assuming your jar has that manifest added in correct place, it looks like It should work as posted.  Can you double-check that the `debateeventplatform-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar` file on your ec2 instance is not an old one?

Comment: Did you solve this issue, and if yes, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a Spring Boot JAR to AWS is easy if you use the correct tools. I prefer using [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) and a good Java IDE such as IntelliJ.

I have no idea how you built your project, if the POM file is valid, did you build a FAT JAR that contains the required dependencies, etc.

If you have never deployed a Spring Boot app to AWS, follow this example in the [AWS Code Lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). Assuming you follow it end to end, you will get the app successfully deployed to AWS cloud:

[Build an application to submit data to a DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_SubmitDataApp_java_2_topic.html)

By the way, the JAR created following this has a MF that works.